# ASP.net WEB API (MVC5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

This question is regarding Web API. I have a Mobile and a ASP.NET MVC5 web application. These application will interact with same DB. I thought instead of writing the code twice, we can have a WEB Api which will interact with DB and return data to the applications.

My Web API should be in MVC5 project/ Solution or I should have this API in separate solution and expose that API to both the application?

Comment: Mobile and a ASP.NET MVC5 web application are separate application?

Comment: What do you mean by Mobile and a ASP.NET MVC5 web application are separate application @AravindSivam. He is asking, I have a Mobile and a ASP.NET MVC5 web application. And now he want to use some interface to interact with DB. His data will be common for both application. So he want to know whether is it good to create a separate Api project in a solution or ...

Comment: @BasantaMatia i'm asking Mobile and a ASP.NET MVC5 web application are separate sites?

Comment: Sry for misunderstood ur comment. Stay good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to keep your **Web Api** and **MVC** Application in a **single project**. Just create a folder in your controller, for example Data, and keep your Api controller here, which must be derived from **ApiController**.

Then add a **WebApiConfig.cs** file in your **App_Start** folder and change the route for your Api's. (You just need to copy your route code from your Api project, if you have already, and place here.)

Then in your Global.asax.cs file, in Application_Start event, call your route for Api. You just need to add this line of code,

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Then add all the required references for Api's through Nuget to your project, For example **System.Web.Http;**

That's it! Hope you understand :)

Comment: Why down voted ?? Can you tell me the reason ?

Comment: This is the first time i am working in API.. pls bare with me... Instead of keeping it as a separate solution like "Web Service", we can have it in the web application solution itself. Rite?? If I expose the API will the mobile app able to consume it?

Comment: Create a ASP.Net MVC 4/5 Application. There is a Controller folder. Create a new Folder, example Data. Keep your Api Controllers there and rest controllers will be in Controller folder. Publish it. Call the api from mobile or Website whatever it will work great